# Struct with two different type properties using templates

Tags: c++

I want to create a struct which holds a key and a value of different types using templates.

I was thinking about using two template values like this:

```
template <typename KEY>
template <typename VALUE>
struct KeyValue {
    KEY key;
    VALUE value;
};

int main() {
    KeyValue<int, int> *kv = new KeyValue<int, int>();
}
```

but this doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: `template <typename KEY, typename VALUE>` it is obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Just put those two arguments in one template

```
template <typename KEY, typename VALUE>
struct KeyValue {
    KEY key;
    VALUE value;
};

int main() {
    KeyValue<int, int> *kv = new KeyValue<int, int>();
    return 0;
}
```

And if you want a key-value contaniner, consider std::map